# How to communicate with device with GPIB?

Tags: c#, usb, visa, gpib

I use "82357B USB/GPIB" in order to communicate with a device with "Agilent Communication Expert".
How can I communicate with the device in C# code? What should I need to install? Which references to add? etc.

And how to diploy the application to another computer? Does the computer need some installations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See "Keysight IO library suit Getting started with Visa.Net C# Instrument control program"
This document describe how to build visual studio solution with visa to communicate with device over GPIB

https://keysightsales.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#1a000000awb5/a/2L0000009JeU/UxdJUjDDylNahqCuK6OHVbjWCycgVq7mZhTdkMgNDDI

Another important document is "Keysight IO Library Suite VISA.NET / C# Quick Reference Guide" (google it)